# Student/Newbie in need of help learning the basics

Tags: mysql

I am tasked with writing a few MySQL queries and I stuck.  I must write a query to show the athlete’s name and the name of their country but only for names that contain the string 'wang' anywhere in the name.

My previous statements queried fine but I am confused on how to achieve the above output.  I am using two different tables and joining them.  Previous statements was:

```
Select * 
FROM ttms 
   Right JOIN country ON ttms.country = country.id 
WHERE color = 'gold';
```

How do  write the correct statement?

Comment: Could you please explain why you included the C++ tag?

Comment: @BatCoder Solved with the overwhelming 10k power of inline tag edits.  

Comment: You really should either Google for a SQL tutorial or ask your instructor for additional help. This is a basic SQL 101 question. SO is not a tutorial site.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or code conversion or tutorial or library finding service** Dont student look at books anymore, or ask their tutors for help

Comment: As I explained earlier (basically with my title), this is all new to me so I do understand the elementary nature of my question to some of you seasoned, well educated veterans; however, I came to this site to seek a little guidance in learning this craft.  I understand that this might be trivial to you but possibly there is someone out there who might understand what I am asking and where I am in the learning process.  I am researching this and reading the materials along with asking questions in different forums.

Comment: @MR12PLAY (Disclaimer ahead: Not an SQL guy.) The problem with question such as this one is not the fact that it is trivial in itself, but rather that questions that show little to no knowledge of the underlying language tend to attract link only answers like the one below (which are borderline not an answer, or a bad answer at best) or would require writing half a tutorial in the answer itself to make it complete. The latter does not work well with this Q/A format. SO just isn't some kind of interactive tutorial or helpdesk, sorry.

Comment: Oh, and it also is not a "forum" in the classical sense, it has no threads of discussion or something like that. The format is: Clear question which has a (small set of) definite answer(s) in the question box, followed by complete and self contained answers below. For more information, visit the [ask]. When looking for learning resources, the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/info) is a good place to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this link,
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

 Use the LIKE keyword to make your query, `%wang%`
From w3schools.com:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE Country LIKE '%land%';
```

Comment: Please make sure to include all the necessary information in the answer itself. Your answer should remain valid even if the linked page changes or disappears.

Comment: Is using the `LIKE` keyword not valid if w3schools kills the page? @BaummitAugen

Comment: Removed my downvote as the answer is probably fine now. Before the edit, it's usefulness without the link was in the range of *"How do I build a treehouse?"* *"Use a hammer."* Not really wrong, but quite incomplete.

Comment: I was reading the question as more of "What do I use to build a treehouse", but thanks for the feedback. @BaummitAugen